# For Each repeating hundreds of times for only a few records

Tags: php, foreach, screen-scraping

I am using the php simple dom parser screen scraper and I am trying to set it up to scrape the contents of a page. The problem is its pulling the data in ok, but its repeating it over and over again and I cant work out why. It seems each record is being repeated over several times.

```
    <?php
    // example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
    include('../simple_html_dom.php');

    // get DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.goldengrovenursery.co.uk/griffin_x/results.asp?txtgenus=Chamaecyparis&txtcultivar=&txtcolour=All&Search=Availability&offset=40');



    echo '<table>
    <thead><th>Genus</th><th>Cultivar</th></thead>
    <tbody>';
    foreach($html->find('td.genus') as $a)
    foreach($html->find('td.cultivar') as $b)
    foreach($html->find('td.species') as $c)
        echo '<tr><td>'.$a->innertext.'</td><td>'.$b->innertext.'</td><td>'.$c->innertext.'</td></tr>';
    echo '</tbody>
    </table>
    ';
    ?>
```

The page its scraping from is here :
http://www.goldengrovenursery.co.uk/griffin_x/results.asp?txtgenus=Chamaecyparis&txtcultivar=&txtcolour=All&Search=Availability&offset=40

The above script ends up looking like this, even though there are only 10 records on the page :

```
    Genus   Cultivar
    Genus       Colour
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       thyoides
    Genus       obtusa
    Genus       lawsoniana
    Genus       obtusa
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       Colour
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       thyoides
    Genus       obtusa
    Genus       lawsoniana
    Genus       obtusa
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       Colour
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       thyoides
    Genus       obtusa
    Genus       lawsoniana
    Genus       obtusa
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus    Cultivar   Colour
    Genus    Cultivar   pisifera
    Genus    Cultivar   pisifera
    Genus    Cultivar   pisifera
    Genus    Cultivar   pisifera
    Genus    Cultivar   pisifera
    Genus    Cultivar   thyoides
    Genus    Cultivar   obtusa
    Genus    Cultivar   lawsoniana
    Genus    Cultivar   obtusa
    Genus    Cultivar   pisifera
    Genus       Colour
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus       thyoides
    Genus       obtusa
    Genus       lawsoniana
    Genus       obtusa
    Genus       pisifera
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   Colour
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   thyoides
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   obtusa
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   lawsoniana
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   obtusa
    Genus   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Genus   NANA    Colour
    Genus   NANA    pisifera
    Genus   NANA    pisifera
    Genus   NANA    pisifera
    Genus   NANA    pisifera
    Genus   NANA    pisifera
    Genus   NANA    thyoides
    Genus   NANA    obtusa
    Genus   NANA    lawsoniana
    Genus   NANA    obtusa
    Genus   NANA    pisifera
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA Colour
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA thyoides
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA obtusa
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA lawsoniana
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA obtusa
    Genus   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA Colour
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA thyoides
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA obtusa
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA lawsoniana
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA obtusa
    Genus   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Genus   SUNGOLD Colour
    Genus   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Genus   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Genus   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Genus   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Genus   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Genus   SUNGOLD thyoides
    Genus   SUNGOLD obtusa
    Genus   SUNGOLD lawsoniana
    Genus   SUNGOLD obtusa
    Genus   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Genus   TOP POINT   Colour
    Genus   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Genus   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Genus   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Genus   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Genus   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Genus   TOP POINT   thyoides
    Genus   TOP POINT   obtusa
    Genus   TOP POINT   lawsoniana
    Genus   TOP POINT   obtusa
    Genus   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   Colour
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   thyoides
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   obtusa
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   lawsoniana
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   obtusa
    Genus   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Genus   NICHOLE Colour
    Genus   NICHOLE pisifera
    Genus   NICHOLE pisifera
    Genus   NICHOLE pisifera
    Genus   NICHOLE pisifera
    Genus   NICHOLE pisifera
    Genus   NICHOLE thyoides
    Genus   NICHOLE obtusa
    Genus   NICHOLE lawsoniana
    Genus   NICHOLE obtusa
    Genus   NICHOLE pisifera
    Genus   RIGID DWARF Colour
    Genus   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Genus   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Genus   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Genus   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Genus   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Genus   RIGID DWARF thyoides
    Genus   RIGID DWARF obtusa
    Genus   RIGID DWARF lawsoniana
    Genus   RIGID DWARF obtusa
    Genus   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   Colour
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   thyoides
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   obtusa
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   lawsoniana
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   obtusa
    Genus   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   Colour
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    Colour
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA Colour
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA Colour
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD Colour
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE Colour
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF Colour
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   Colour
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    Colour
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA Colour
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA Colour
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD Colour
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE Colour
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF Colour
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   Colour
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   FILIFERA NANA   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    Colour
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA    pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA Colour
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NANA AUREOVARIEGATA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA Colour
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SQUARROSA SULPHUREA pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD Colour
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   SUNGOLD pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TOP POINT   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TSATSUMI GOLD   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE Colour
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   NICHOLE pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF Colour
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   RIGID DWARF pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   Colour
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis   TRUE BLUE   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   Colour
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   thyoides
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   obtusa
    Chamaecyparis    Cultivar   pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       Colour
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
    Chamaecyparis       thyoides
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       lawsoniana
    Chamaecyparis       obtusa
    Chamaecyparis       pisifera
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'er searching the whole document for `cultivar` with your second `foreach()` loop, not simply the `genus` that you're already found with the first `foreach()`; and similarly for `species` within `cultivar`

But because each entry is actually in its own row in a nested table, you also need to backtrack up through the dom for each entry:

```
foreach($html->find('td.genus') as $a)
foreach($a->parent()->parent()->find('td.cultivar') as $b)
foreach($b->parent()->parent()->find('td.species') as $c)
```

Better variable naming might also make this clearer:

```
foreach($html->find('td.genus') as $genus) {
    foreach($genus->parent()->parent()->find('td.cultivar') as $cultivar) {
        foreach($cultivar->parent()->parent()->find('td.species') as $species) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . 
                $genus->innertext .
                '</td><td>' .
                $cultivar->innertext .
                '</td><td>' .
                $species->innertext.
                '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Iv tried the above but that just gives me a blank page with just the table headers.

Comment: The problem is that each of the items are returned in an array, so I get 10x genus, 10x cultivar and 10x species, what I need to do is print them out row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

```
<?php
    // example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    // get DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.goldengrovenursery.co.uk/griffin_x/results.asp?txtgenus=Chamaecyparis&txtcultivar=&txtcolour=All&Search=Availability&offset=40');



    echo "<div style='float:left'>";
    foreach($html->find('td.genus') as $genus)

    echo '<div>'.$genus->innertext.'</div>';

     echo "</div><div style='float:left'>";
    foreach($html->find('td.cultivar') as $species)

    echo '<div>'.$species->innertext.'</div>';

    echo '</div><div>';
    foreach($html->find('td.species') as $cultivar)
          echo '<div>'.$cultivar->innertext.'</div>';
            echo '</div>
    ';
    ?>
```